# Design tab disappears after adding TabLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I can't add TabLayout because it removes everything that is on design tab and it won't even show up in Component Tree.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncd27.png)

Tried to Repair IDE but that doesn't work.
Issue panel only shows that there are missing constrains, that's not what I need I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after updating Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

If your parent layout is ConstraintLayout, then you need to set at least one horizontal or vertical constraint for your tablayout.

for example)

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```